# Increasing efficiency of my predictors in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I have been working on a project related to late arrival of aircrafts in 2019 across top 10 US airports.

The dataset has more than 140000 observations.(DELAY - is in mins, Cancelled, diverted,delay30 are boolean)

```
FL_DATE,FL_DAY,FL_MONTH,CARRIER,ORIGIN,DEP_DELAY,ARR_DELAY,CANCELLED,DIVERTED,DELAY30_MINS

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,LAX,21,12,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,SFO,0,8,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,JFK,0,20,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,DFW,27,39,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,LAX,0,1,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,DEN,0,14,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,JFK,23,40,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,SFO,12,24,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,LAS,15,6,0,0,1

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,DFW,38,10,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,SEA,0,24,0,0,1

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,ORD,31,28,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,LAX,4,5,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,DFW,22,9,0,0,0

1/1/2019,Tuesday,January,AA,ORD,6,2,0,0,0
```

I have been doing plots and modelling on it. I am predicting the accuracy of 4 attributes namely FL_MONTH, FL_DAY. CANCELLED and DIVERTED.

For predicting FL_MONTH and FL_DAY, I use rpart, j48, random forest in method.
For predicting CANCELLED and DIVERTED, I use rpart, glm, random forest and naive bayes in method.

```
#Using a 75% training and 25% testing split (Removed FL_DATE before training)
    
month.rpart.fit = train(FL_MONTH ~ ., data = DF.train, method = "rpart", tuneLength = 5,trControl=trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10))
varImp(month.rpart.fit)
month.rpart.pred = predict(month.rpart.fit, DF.test)
confusionMatrix(month.rpart.pred, DF.test$FL_MONTH)
```

Here are my prediction results

FL_MONTH using 3 classifiers are around 12%,
FL_DAY using 3 classifiers are around 18%,
CANCELLED using 4 classifiers are around 95%,
DIVERTED using 4 classifiers are around 99%

Here are the 2 issues which I am not able to understand/fix

1st issue: Since FL_MONTH and FL_DAY are multi classification problems, I am using tree based classifiers and the accuracy is very poor. I am not sure on how to increase the accuracy. I tried training FL_MONTH against all other 8 class variables, then mix and matched with select few but the accuracy is always between 10 - 12%. Is there a different classifier I can use or is there a way to increase accuracy?

Variable importance and confusion matrix for random forest when predicting FL_MONTH

[image]

[image]

2nd issue: CANCELLED and DIVERTED predictions are good but for some reason the specificity is less than 10% using rpart and random forest and in 0 for glm and Naive Bayes. This makes Neg Pred Value NaN for the latter 2 cases. Is there a way to increase specificity and Neg Pred value?

Variable importance and confusion matrix for random forest when predicting CANCELLATIONS
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is due class imbalance. Common way to approach the issue is to use sampling methods such as down-sampling the more abundant class, up-sampling the minority class, and some fancier sampling methods like SMOTE and ROSE. Another way is to tune the decision threshold. And yet a third way is to give different weights to the classes - only ML algos that support this sort of thing. Both random forest and rpart support class weights.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was really struggling with this. I will try the down and up sampling first.

Comment: you can use the `sampling` argument to [`trainControl`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/trainControl).